# How to call a .txt file and find multiple strings of .txt file from a folder or directory using batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am new here. I found the way to find only one string from a directory.

```
 findstr /S /M /C:"string" /C:folder *.txt
```

I can get success for only one string. But my wish is to find a solution, where i will write my wanted multiple strings in a file and will call that file by command and write the directory or folder name, where these information can be found.

i found some information from this forum but i could not succeeded.

```
@echo off
set RESULT_FILE="result.txt"
set /p "var1=Enter the String to Find: "

pushd %~p0
type NUL > %RESULT_FILE%.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S *.txt') do (
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%c in ('find /i /c "%var1%" "%%a"') do (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('find /i "%var1%" "%%a"') do if %%c neq 0 echo %%f
)
) >> "%RESULT_FILE%".tmp
move %RESULT_FILE%.tmp %RESULT_FILE% >nul 2>&1

:: Open the file
"%RESULT_FILE%"
popd
```

this code is also not working for me... after run, i get a blank result.txt file

I hope you already experienced the same problem and can help me to get rid of that problem.

If you have any questions, please let me know. I will be happy to answer. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /r /s /m "string1 string2 string3" *.txt
```

Space seperates search terms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am searching for a solution, where i can show a txt file, and  the operation will done by each line string.

actually i have a lot of txt files with string in a folder. i only need some strings , for example 50 or 60. so i prefer a solution, where i only show the txt file and the operation will be done automatically and i will get all information in a separate txt file. i prefer bash solution for this job. please help me.

Comment: If you want a bash script then why ask in a BATCH group. We don't do BASH we are MICROSOFT WINDOWS. It is also tagged CMD which is also Windows. Try reading the descriptions of your tags before using.

Comment: hey, sorry for my mistake. it was a mistake when i tried to wrote batch. i need batch file or cmd , so that i can make my work simple to find the strings inside the text from a folder. and i need this for Microsoft windows 7 OS. @noodlesstillalive 
 do you know any solution to make it simple for me. tried a lot of commands but still no result. hope someone will be kind enough to share his/her experience here. please help